# Pytest - @pytest.mark.parametrize() how to use when changes in one field in post request

Tags: django, testing, django-rest-framework, pytest

I'm really sorry but i dont know how to describe my problem in one line so please change if its wrong.
so the problem is i'm using unit test in my drf test cases and there are two test cases such as

```
def test_with_blank_addressstate(self):
    # view = order_list, method = POST
    # user = Normal
    # Country = IN, state = ""
    self.client.login(
        username=self.order.owner.username, password="normal"
    )
    url = reverse("order_list")
    self.order["addressstate"] = ""
    response = self.client.post(url, self.order, format="json")

    self.assertIn(
        "{'addressstate': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.'",
        response.data["error"]["description"],
    )

def test_with_incorrect_addressstate(self):
    # view = order_list, method = POST
    # user = Normal
    # Country = IN, state = GJJ(Incorrect)
    self.client.login(
        username=self.order.owner.username, password="normal"
    )
    url = reverse("order_list")
    self.order["addressstate"] = "SRJ"
    response = self.client.post(url, self.order, format="json")

    self.assertIn(
        "{'addressstate': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.'",
        response.data["error"]["description"],
    )
```

both test cases i perfectly fine. but my test cases are increasing, i want to test every field for different-different data.
for the above test cases if i want to create only one test case and only want to change the field addressstate every time in post request so i can test it on differents values of addressstate field.
i never used pytest only know the basic.but i think i can do this using pytest.
can you guys help me out how i can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an example for your case:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "order, error_message",
    [
        pytest.param(
            "", "error pla pla", id="first_case"
        ),
        pytest.param(
            "SRJ", "error pla pla pla", id="second_case"
        ),
    ],
)
def test_with_for_two_cases(self,order, error_message):
    # view = order_list, method = POST
    # user = Normal
    # Country = IN, state = GJJ(Incorrect)
    self.client.login(
        username=self.order.owner.username, password="normal"
    )
    url = reverse("order_list")
    self.order["addressstate"] = order
    response = self.client.post(url, self.order, format="json")

    self.assertIn(
        "{'addressstate': [ErrorDetail(string=  {error_message}",
        response.data["error"]["description"],
    )
```